# JBoss EAP 6.1 Error : This runtime type requires a JDK. The current default VM for this server's execution environment is not recognized as a JDK

Tags: java, jboss, server, jboss6.x, jboss-eap-6

You can check this warning [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L153i.jpg) when I'm adding the server I'm getting like this. Please help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I know I am late to answer but I hope this can help someone.
Well this error means that you need to point on your JDK not JRE : on Eclipse go to window -> preferences

[image]

Comment: @DmainEvent Click on the link it's an image, you need check JDK not JRE (preferences -> java -> installed JREs)

Answer (score 3):

Go to

***window -> preferances -> java -> installed jres***

Click "Add" and add the JDK path.

[image]